# asp.net mvc and custom membership and role providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

My question, is it possible to build customer membership and role providers (overriding the asp.net providers) when using asp.net mvc?

I am guessing it is possible but have not seen any information about it.

Would it be done the same way as in asp.net?  Just changing the web.config to point to a new provider and then providing the override methods?

I have found many articles discussing changing the data source of the membership and role providers but I don't like the tables that asp.net uses so I usually use my own table structure.

If you have any articles or links that talk about this that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, the providers are exactly the same and work just like they do in "regular" asp.net.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you tried it by any chance?  I'm still getting use to MVC and have not gotten around to the authentication part yet.

Comment: Yeah, in testing I'm using the SQLProvider against their typical ASPNET database.  However in production, I use the ActiveDirectory authorization pieces.  It was just a matter of switching providers in web.config and it all works perfect.

Comment: I use the lightweight PAB.Web.Providers I got from an eggheadcafe.com article in my MVC project and they work as expected.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm looking forward to trying it out.